# How to create an accumulated percentage list that takes percentage value of year x and multiplies it by the percenteage value of year x+1?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, accumulate

Sorry if my title makes no sense, let me explain. I have a table that consists of years and the percentage of salary readjustment for that year:

| Year | Percentage_readjustment |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1.028 |
| 2021 | 1.027 |
| 2022 | 1.061 |
| 2023 | 1.120 |

What I want to do is calculate the percentage of accumulated readjustment, which is the percentage of readjustment from the previous year multiplied by the percentage of readjustment of the current year. For example, in 2021 the percentage of accumulated readjustment would be 1.028 * 1.027, which equals 1.055756.

I turned the table into a list with tuples using zip:

```
year = [2020, 2021, 2022, 2023]
perc_readjust = [1.028, 1.027, 1.061, 1.120]
annual_readjust = list(zip(year, perc_readjust))
```

So the new list is this:

```
annual_readjust = [(2020, 1.028), (2021, 1.027), (2022, 1.061), (2023, 1.12)]
```

And this is where I get lost. I think it makes sense to use loops, but I don't know how to code that. My idea is that first it will multiply annual_readjustment[0][1] by annual_readjustment[1][1], and then that value by annual_readjustment[2][1] and so on. I have no idea where to go from here, please help. :(

The list I would expect to be created would be this:

```
accumulated_readjust = [(2020, 1.028000), (2021, 1.055756), (2022, 1.12016), (2023, 1.25458)]
```

These are the values calculated with Excel.

Comment: Are you able to use `pandas` ?

Comment: I could use pandas, but I don't know how exactly.

Answer (score 0):

With `pandas` lib it's easy to calculate cumulative product:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Year': [2020, 2021, 2022, 2023], 'Perc_readjust':[1.028, 1.027, 1.061, 1.120]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Accum_readjust'] = df['Perc_readjust'].cumprod()
print(df)
```

---

```
   Year  Perc_readjust  Accum_readjust
0  2020          1.028        1.028000
1  2021          1.027        1.055756
2  2022          1.061        1.120157
3  2023          1.120        1.254576
```